# write table with spaces before row names

Tags: r

I have a data frame that writes out to a table with a header name at the top. Here's some reproducible code.

```
library(gdata)
df = as.list(c(1:100))
df = unlist(df)
dim(df) = c(length(df)/5, 5)
array_name = as.data.frame(c("Data:"))
write.fwf(array_name,'new_file.txt',append=T,sep="     ",colnames=F,rownames=F,quote=F)
write.fwf(df,'new_file.txt',append=T,sep="      ",colnames=F,rownames=F,quote=F)
```

Here is the output...

```
Data:
 1      21      41      61       81
 2      22      42      62       82
 3      23      43      63       83
 4      24      44      64       84
 5      25      45      65       85
 6      26      46      66       86
 7      27      47      67       87
 8      28      48      68       88
 9      29      49      69       89
10      30      50      70       90
11      31      51      71       91
12      32      52      72       92
13      33      53      73       93
14      34      54      74       94
15      35      55      75       95
16      36      56      76       96
17      37      57      77       97
18      38      58      78       98
19      39      59      79       99
20      40      60      80      100
```

How can I make it look like this...

```
Data:
        0:        1      21      41      61       81
        5:        2      22      42      62       82
       10:        3      23      43      63       83
       15:        4      24      44      64       84
       20:        5      25      45      65       85
       25:        6      26      46      66       86
       30:        7      27      47      67       87
       35:        8      28      48      68       88
       40:        9      29      49      69       89
       45:       10      30      50      70       90
       50:       11      31      51      71       91
       55:       12      32      52      72       92
       60:       13      33      53      73       93
       65:       14      34      54      74       94
       70:       15      35      55      75       95
       75:       16      36      56      76       96
       80:       17      37      57      77       97
       85:       18      38      58      78       98
       90:       19      39      59      79       99
      100:       20      40      60      80      100
```

So, Basically I want to:

1) add the row name column that intervals by 5.

2) make each column line up on the right.

3) shift everything to the right of the header name (lining up with the first digit of the last line - i.e. "100".

Edit/Solution:

This is what I did to solve the problem. I substituted "df" for "G" because that is the variable I was using for my script.

```
array_name <- as.data.frame(c("G:"))
G <- as.list(t(dflist2$`1`[2][!dflist2$`1`[2] == ""]))
G <- unlist(G)
dim(G) <- c(length(G)/5, 5)
G <- as.data.frame(G)
G <- cbind(row = 0, G)
for (x in 1:nrow(G)) {
  if (row.names(G[x,]) == "1") {G[x,"row"] = 0
  } else {G[x,"row"] = G[x-1,"row"]+5}
}
row.names(G) <- sprintf("   %i:", G$row)
G <- G[,-1]
write.fwf(array_name, 'new_file.txt', append = TRUE, sep = "", 
colnames = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
write.fwf(G,'new_file.txt',append=TRUE,sep="      ", 
colnames=FALSE,rownames=TRUE,quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to spend some time with an R tutorial or two. You have a lot of redundancy (creating a list and then unlisting it) in your code. I'm assuming that you did not mean to drop 95 between 90 and 100 so I start with 5 not 0:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:100, 20, 5))
array_name <- "Data:"
writeLines(array_name, "new_file.txt")
row.names(df) <- sprintf("%8d:", seq(0, 95, by=5))
write.fwf(df, 'new_file.txt', append=TRUE ,sep="      ", colnames=FALSE,
     rownames=TRUE, quote=FALSE)
```

Some of this is just good practice like using <- instead of = makes your code easier to read. Using `FALSE` rather than F. `FALSE` is a reserved word and cannot be reassigned. F is an abbreviation that can be reassigned. If somewhere in your code you accidentally assign a variable F to any value other than 0, your code is broken.

Comment: For reference, I've edited my code to produce the same result. I should have used "%8d:" instead of "%8.0d" in sprintf().